# Can I prevent a Windows computer from going to sleep under certain conditions?

Tags: windows, rendering, sleep, power-saving, hibernation

I have a Windows 10 computer that's typically used for rendering. It is therefore vital that the computer does not go into any kind of power-saving mode while either the CPUs or GPU is running at high capacity, regardless of user input (i.e. over night). So usually, I just turn off all power saving.

To save energy I would still like the computer to do enter sleep or hibernation mode when it has been internally idle (like: average CPU/ GPU utilization < 20% within the last 20 minutes). Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks for your support!

Comment: I had started to look up the [SetThreadExecutionState](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-setthreadexecutionstate) API for you. Then I realized you aren't explicitly programming anything.  The rendering code itself doesn't have anything to turn off sleep mode?

Comment: Hey Selbie, thank you, I had a look and in principle the SetThreadExecutionState function seems to do what I need, I just don't know how to call it from within the 3D program that's initiating the render process. I thought it might somehow be possible to execute the function with the start of the 3D app, but the documentation you linked states that it "simply resets the idle timer", so it would have to be called continuously to avoid hibernation.